# Java - a GUI update button

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

i am trying to making an update button in my GUI form that can be edit a record in my DB but i missing something that i hope someone to help me

this the code of update method:

```
public int updateUser(Login user) //int
{
    DatabaseConnection dbconn = new DatabaseConnection();
    Connection conn = dbconn.getConn();

    int rows = 0;
    try 
    {
        String sql = "UPDATE LOGIN set USER_NAME = ? ,  PASSWORD = ? , PRIVILEGE_ID = ?";
        PreparedStatement pStm = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        //fill SQL parameters from user: //
        pStm.setString(1, user.getUserName());
        pStm.setString(2, user.getPassword());
        pStm.setInt(3, user.getPrivilegeId());
        rows = 
                pStm.executeUpdate();
    }
    catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    finally
    {
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());;
        }
    }
    return rows;
}
```

code in java swing for update button:

```
private void updateUserLayerActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
     // 1-get data from user and check it: //
    String _name = nameLayer.getText().trim();
    String _paswrd = passLayer.getText().trim();
    String _prvName = privLayer.getSelectedItem().toString();

    //get Privilege_Id from DB:
    PrivilegeHandeler prvHndler = new PrivilegeHandeler();
    int prvId = prvHndler.getPrivilegeByName(_prvName);

    if(_name.length() >0 && _paswrd.length() >0 && prvId> 0)
    {
        Login user = new Login();
        user.setUserName(_name);
        user.setPassword(_paswrd);
        user.setPrivilegeId(prvId);

        //update User: //
        loginHandeler loghndlr = new loginHandeler();

        int rows = 
                loghndlr.updateUser(user);


        if (rows >0)
        {
            usrFormErorr.setText("user has been added successfully :)");
            nameLayer.setText("");
            passLayer.setText("");
            privLayer.setSelectedIndex(0);
        }
        else
        {
            usrFormErorr.setText("updated failed, try again");
        }
    }

    else
    {
        usrFormErorr.setText("please, fill the required fields first");
    }
}
```

My problem is this:

1-i am trying to enter an info to edit then update but always get an error updated failed, try again that i made it to get a message when there is a problem

Kindly help. A working code would be very highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: your update statement doesn't have a where clause, so you're updating all your rows.  That seems fishy.  Also, don't print the exception and then return, since you'll be hiding the actual exception (there won't be a difference between zero rows changed or an exception happening).  Instead, wrap the exception in a RuntimeException (for now) and rethrow it.  If then you still get 0, that means your table is empty.  Then you probably want an insert instead of an update.

Comment: if your LOGIN table has more than one row and USER_NAME is primary key or set to be unique, you will get an constraint error since you are updating all rows with the same data - probably you want to update the record whose USER_NAME is the one given, that is, USER_NAME should only appear in the where clause, not in the SET part. If you want to update the name, you must use the old name to identify the row.

Comment: AND if you want to **add** an user (assumption based on your message "user has been added ...:") then an UPDATE statement will not work, you need an INSERT one. Advice: use `ex.printStackTrace()` instead of printing (only) the exception message, often there there is a second Exception *linked* to the first one.